# VS2013 Clickonce Unknown Publisher

Tags: visual-studio-2013, clickonce, code-signing, digital-certificate

I'm trying to deploy a ClickOnce application, but I keep getting an Unverified Publisher message only when the target PC is not connected to the internet.

[image: Security Warning Image]

As soon as the computer connects to the internet, the installer decides that the application is from a verified publisher and all looks good. It lists my app and company name, and when you click on the company name, the certificate opens up.

This is an issue since some of our customers use computers which are totally isolated from the internet.

I'm signing using a DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID certificate and VS2013. The certification path goes back to the DigiCert Assured ID Root CA.

[image: Cert image]

Also, The DigiCert Assured ID Root CA certificate shows up in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities list on the target PC.

The Unverified Publisher prompt goes away if the program is installed once and then re-installed, or if the PC is connected to the internet. I've tried manually signing using signtool, and that seems to mess up the computed hash. Does anyone have any experience with this or ideas as to what might be happening here?

Thanks!
Dan